# Deleting last item on GridView an error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I'm deleting items in GridView no error occur but when last item deleting in GridView an error occur.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["dtCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dtCart"];
            dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Session["dtCart"] = dt;




            int totalQauntity = 0; int totalAmount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                totalQauntity = totalQauntity + int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["QUANTITY"].ToString());
                totalAmount = totalAmount + int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["AMOUNT"].ToString());
            }

            ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblQuantity")).Text = totalQauntity.ToString();
            ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblAmount")).Text = totalAmount.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/ViewCart.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/Error Message.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYW23.png)

Comment: Readers will generally ask you to provide your code, data and error logs as text, not images. A code formatting tool is provided for this purpose. Would you edit your question please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, your question is not going to get much help in it's current format... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When you delete the last item in your `DataTable` and then bind the empty table to your `GridView`, you effectively have an empty `GridView` which means no footer, which in turn means no `lblQuantity` or `lblAmount` controls exist on your page and thus they cannot be found, i.e. _referenced_.

Comment: How to solve this problem?

Comment: @Hafiz it depends on the result you are looking for. The easiest solution is to check for a null object reference before you attempt to update the text on your label controls.. e.g.  var lblQ = ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblQuantity")); if(lblQ != null) {lblQ.Text = totalQauntity.ToString();}

Comment: can you write correct code ?

Comment: The two hardest parts of programming are off by one errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the last item in your `DataTable` and then bind the empty table to your `GridView`, you effectively have an empty `GridView` which means no footer, which in turn means no `lblQuantity` or `lblAmount` controls exist on your page and thus they cannot be found, i.e. *referenced*.

For a fast and dirty answer..

Replace these **three** lines...

```
((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblQuantity")).Text = totalQauntity.ToString();
((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblAmount")).Text = totalAmount.ToString();
Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/ViewCart.aspx");
```

with...

```
// check footer row is not null
if(GridView1.FooterRow != null)
{
    // save control you want to edit to a variable
    var lblQty = ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblQuantity"));
    if(lblQty != null) 
    {
        // only update the text if it's not null
        lblQty.Text = totalQauntity.ToString();
    }

    var lblAmt = ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblAmount"));
    if(lblAmt != null) 
    {
        lblAmt.Text = totalAmount.ToString();
    }
}

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/ViewCart.aspx");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/Error Message.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Still have same problem..

Comment: I have Replaced these lines with your code but still facing same error..

Comment: @Hafiz I overlooked the `FooterRow` check for null. I've updated the code you should try.

Comment: Your code is working but when refreshing the page the same error occurs

Comment: @Hafiz I'm going to guess the error on refresh occurs because you have similar logic used in your `GridView1_RowDeleting` in another function that is used when you load the page. Basically you are trying to show the `RowFooter` values when you have an empty cart. I've given you enough of an answer here that you should be able to fix the other error. If not then you should post it as a separate question. Best of luck.

Comment: I have Replaced these lines with your code but still facing same error. Basically I want when cart is empty redirect to  "Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/Error Message.aspx"); " but when last item is deleting an error occurs..

Comment: Problem are not solved. I'm only saying if I refresh page or delete last item in GridView the same error occur..

Comment: Your question has morphed into something more than the original post indicated. Also, I believe you have all the information you need if you were to take a minute and think critically about your problem. That said, I've made one last and final update. Note that you now have **three** lines to replace instead of two.

Comment: After using your code showing "Total amount" and "Total quantity" zero however error solved

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck. Also, the reason I said, *it depends on the result you are looking for* in my original comment was because of the zero's you now see. For the record I consider my solution a poor one but it was quick and dirty for the code you had. Personally I would approach this differently; I wouldn't use redirects and instead I would reload the page and control when the `DataBind` occurs in the page load based on post backs versus page gets.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my error. You have excellent developing knowledge. I have one more error in my project. if I post another question how can reach to you...?

Comment: @Hafiz Unfortunately that's not how stackoverflow works. Stackoverflow is about answers that help you and the next person who might encounter the issue. Just post a well formed question that follows the 'how to ask' guidelines and someone will help if they can. You can review the guidelines here.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guidelines.